# summation symbol with square?

Tags: statistics, notation

If $$\sum\beta=2\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_i\right) \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}y_i\right)-N\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_iy_i  \right]$$ $$B={\sum\alpha\sum\epsilon-\sum\beta \sum\delta \over \sum\alpha\sum\gamma-\sum^2\beta}, $$
how can I calculate $$\sum\nolimits^2\beta? $$

The original formula come from [Kasa Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrX1e.png).

Comment: As written, you are just doubling each term, so $\sum 2\beta=20$.  I am sure that is not what you meant, but I do not know what you do mean.  Please clarify

Comment: Sorry for my misleading. The post question are rectified. $$∑^2\beta$$ rather than $$∑2\beta$$

Comment: There is a difference between $\sum$, which is the summation symbol, and $\Sigma$, which is just a Greek letter used as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

In the page you linked, $\Sigma_\beta^2$ means $\left(\Sigma_\beta\right)^2$.

$\Sigma_\beta$ is defined in the second line of part (1).

Comment: Thank you very much!